# Google Map not working on android App build on PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm trying to build an android app using PhoneGap and sencha touch. Google map is not working and is throwing the below error :

code: 3 message : TimeOut

Here is the code I'm using to get the coordinates :

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var options = { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
}
```

I made sure the AndroidManifest file have permissions : `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and the navigator is enabled in the device.

Please help me out if there is anything wrong with the code or the permissions.

Comment: Are you using it on a device that actually has google maps on it ?

Comment: Your code looks fine even though your post title is a bit off. You are using the WebView's geolocation capabilities not Google Maps. 

Are you doing this on a device or the emulator? The emulator is notoriously bad on getting geolocation data. Try running "adb logcat" to see what the log messages are in a console window.

Comment: I have a same problem. I am using sencha touch to make my app. Google maps not visible in Android Emulator. But showing in iOS and browser

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a general problem phonegap can't operate with GPS. It work's just when running the application for the first time.